# Moving cards from one list to another

Tags: manatee.trello

I am having an issue were my trello board won't update from my below code sets the "CurrentCard" to list 4 on my trello board. I looked at [Manatee.Trello Moving Cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926431/manatee-trello-moving-cards) but i am not sure i am following.

```
var CurrentCard = Trelloboard.Lists[index].Cards[CardIndex];
CurrentCard.Position = 4;
```

Comment: What is your goal here? Are you trying to move a card to another list, or change the position of the card within the current list?

Comment: I looked into it more and i was using the wrong portion from the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
            var otherList  = Trelloboard.Lists.Last();//The List to which you want to move the card to.

            var CurrentCard = Trelloboard.Lists[index].Cards[0];// The current card you want to move

            CurrentCard.List = otherList;//applying the "otherList" to the "CurrentCard"'s List attribute.
```